Issue with Black Background When Extracting Images from PDF Using PyMuPDF
I am trying to extract images from a PDF file using PyMuPDF (fitz), but I am encountering an issue where the extracted images have a black background. How can I extract images while preserving a transparent background?
I suspect it might be related to the PDF file or image format. If anyone has encountered a similar issue, I would appreciate your help!
Thank you!
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import io
import os
from PIL import Image

def extract_images_from_pdf(pdf_path, output_folder):
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)

    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)

    for page_number in range(len(doc)):
        page = doc[page_number]
        image_list = page.get_images(full=True)

        for img_index, img in enumerate(image_list):
            xref = img[0]
            base_image = doc.extract_image(xref)
            image_bytes = base_image["image"]

            real_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))

            image_filename = f"page_{page_number + 1}_image_{img_index + 1}.png"
            image_path = os.path.join(output_folder, image_filename)

            real_image.save(image_path)

    doc.close()

# Set PDF path and output folder
pdf_path = "sample.pdf"
output_folder = "extracted_images"

extract_images_from_pdf(pdf_path)

When I run this code, the extracted images display a black background instead of being transparent, even when they should have a transparent background.
